# How to set a app tile properties for a Universal Windows App

Tags: windows-10

This used to be done in the appmanifest but the option appears to have disappeared for Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

Tiles still go in the manifest. Visual Studio 2015RC doesn't have a visual manifest editor so you will need to edit the XML directly. You can find the full schema in the [uap:VisualElements documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn934817.aspx) or can see the basics in the wizard based or sample apps:

```
  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="App181"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
    Description="App181"
    BackgroundColor="#464646">
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
  </uap:VisualElements>
```